Is pragmatism a theory of epistemology? What are its tenets?
This is a very good essay on pragmatism that I will absorb with time. I ask this as a supplementary question.
In order to accept tenets or assertions associated with pragmatism, I would expect there to be theoretical argumentation for them. And yet, pragmatism sometimes sounds like an anti-theory, almost more of a subjective and normative attitude that rejects the need for full-fledged epistemological justification of anything.
To say that people should work on theories that are “useful” or “work in the real world” sounds like it requires elaboration on what one thinks “useful” means. But because pragmatism sounds so anti-theoretical and anti-skeptical, I wonder if a pragmatist would claim precisely that the notion of “useful” doesn’t need theoretical dissection.
This makes me wonder if pragmatism isn’t really a theory, because it decidedly rejects theorization, in a way, so it doesn’t want to be logically derived from first principles or anything.
Is pragmatism an epistemology, or is it the rejection of epistemology?

I wonder if a pragmatist would claim precisely that the notion of “useful” doesn’t need theoretical dissection. Many pragmatists might agree with this, but the disagreements between Peirce and James suggest pragmatists need to dissect it more carefully.

Indeed pragmatism rejects the traditional formalistic epistemologies that focus on finding absolute abstract justifications for beliefs, instead emphasizing action, results, and the practical cash value of ideas. So pragmatism might not fully reject epistemology but instead offers a distinct and more practical conception of it within a temporary foggy epistemic forest full of simulacra and simulations...

Interesting question! Pragmatism seems to blur the lines between theory and practical application. Does its focus on 'usefulness' challenge traditional epistemology, or redefine it entirely?

No! It is about experience, not knowledge! Remember, with pragmatism, no matter the brand and flavor, it is always about experience and all truth and belief claims will derive from that. So much epistemology has corrupted our insight into our own experiences and this makes us model-centric. As a result, we mistakenly put the abstract before the concrete. This is dangerous to do and if we are open to philosophy--the power of inquiry and asking questions--we must be open to the concrete as a standard bearer for our abstractions. Otherwise, we will be on what John Dewey called "the quest for certainty." No pragmatists will accept the closed view of thinking that some paradigm or theory of epistemology will set you free; only your experience can do that. In the case of self-interpretation, we are constantly questioning our own goals, motives, purposes, etc. and this is what the practice of philosophy is all about. But it would be a mistake to adopt some view of the self, i.e. Stoicism, Utilitarianism, etc. and use that as a substitute filter through which to view all of our experience. This would cheapen the self and the adventures of life that make life worth living. Before we can get to the examined life we have to be open to the openness of experience itself. All theories, as Husserl taught, "bracket" experience in some fashion.

This answer is from the perspective of Peirce (1903 Harvard lectures, specifically lectures 5-7).
Pragmatism is part of the normative science of logic (the part dealing with abduction, hypothesizing), not a descriptive theory of knowledge (and is independent of any special science like psychology).
Logic restrains bad reasoning. Pragmatism, as the logic of abduction, restrains its user from introducing unclear concepts into hypotheses. What this means is that pragmatism restricts reasoning to concepts with some conceivable practical consequence.
The epistemological theory behind pragmatism would be in the cotary propositions, which hold that that all concepts derive from perception, broadly taken to include generals and even rudimentary abduction. However, Peirce says that pragmatism would be basically correct even discounting this theory. So, to evaluate pragmatism, you would have to compare it with potential competing standards of abduction (which Peirce does do), rather than with epistemological theories.

There's a subtle mistake in this phrase, above:

people should work on theories that are “useful” or “work in the real
world"

When we use 'useful' or 'work in the real world' this way we implicitly assign a generalized absolute worth to a given theory: e.g. the Theory of Gravity is 'useful' but Orgone theory is not 'useful'. But that's exactly opposite of what Pragmatism aims for. Pragmatism suggests that a theory should have a use — a specific, direct, practical use — and we should not be worrying about its generalized absolute worth. So, if we want to build a rocket we need to account for gravity, so the concept of gravity and any theories about it are useful and meaningful. But if we want to address (say) world hunger, there is no obvious way that gravity plays any part in the problem or its solution, and so the concept of gravity and any theories related to it are entirely empty.
Pragmatism is basically a 'tools in the toolshed' approach. We want to pull out tools that are useful for a given job, and then put them back when we're done. We don't want to waste time and effort trying to find the 'perfect' tool in some absolute sense, nor do we want to carry all our tools around, all the time. Pragmatism isn't anti-theoretical or anti-skeptical (odd turn of phrase, that). It's against a kind of epistemological idealism that insists on "knowing what's right"; it tries to keep us focussed on "knowing what works".
There's an interesting overlap with Wittgenstein's later work, where language is determined by use-value. It makes me curious whether or not Wittgenstein read the American Pragmatists (which was not popular theory in Russell's circle).

I have found myself attracted to pragmatic thinking, but like you, I too had difficulty understanding what theory was behind the pragmatic perspective.  I was not helped by the citations and books I sampled from pragmatic philosophers.  What I finally realized was that pragmatism seems to primarily consist of a commitment to a different truth standard than most philosophers adopt. Rather than absolute or logical truth, pragmatism appears to redefine truth solely based on an effectiveness utility.
YES, if one challenges "what is effectiveness" or "effectiveness for what", then pragmatists have limited further grounding.  One can set short term objectives, and do pragmatism as a local process.  Or one can reference Darwinian survival.  But as with every instance of further justification, Munchausen's Trilemma rears up, and ultimately no justification closes.
Logical truth is a central assumption behind all analytic philosophy, the dominant approach to philosophy in the Anglo-American tradition, and this is how most of us are trained in philosophy.  So the pragmatic alternative is -- foreign to how most of us are taught.  Note that logic itself, and its justification, is ALSO subject to Munchausen's limits.  And given that there are an infinity of different logics, and none of them can be justified, the logical/analytic truth metric is no more justified than the pragmatic standard is.
Pragmatism, however, can ACCEPT an unjustifiable truth standard, while analyticity -- basically cannot.  And pragmatism can support analyticity as a useful but flawed methodology, while the flaws in analyticity's justification make it fail its own truth standard.  So both failing Munchausen is -- advantage to pragmatism.


"Philosopher William James, a prominent pragmatist, discussed the
concept of the "Will to Believe," suggesting that in certain
situations, believing something (like a higher power) could be
beneficial even without definitive proof. "


"Pragmatism philosophy itself is not inherently atheist; it does not
necessarily deny the existence of God, but rather focuses on the
practical consequences and usefulness of beliefs, meaning a pragmatist
could hold religious beliefs if they find them beneficial in their
life, while still evaluating them based on their practical impact. "

pragmatism philosophy

Maybe a "pragmatic atheist" is not a pragmatist that does not believe in God...

@MauroALLEGRANZA - It is too complicated. Nowadays, they (the majority) understand only two scenarios: you believe in "bearded guy sitting on a cloud" or you don't.
